# If greater than equal to

Tags: linux, shell-script, rhel

I'm trying to write a shell script in redhat Linux which will send an email if there are processes running more than 2 hours. Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/sh
RESULT=find /proc -maxdepth 1 -user gen17 -type d -mmin +120 | wc -l;
if [ "$RESULT -ge 1" ];
then
find /proc -maxdepth 1 -user gen17 -type d -mmin +120 -exec basename {} \; | mail -s 'process running more than 2 hours' <myemail>
fi
echo "now sleeping for 2 mins"
sleep 120
done
```

According to me I should send an email only if the result is greater than or equal to 1, however, if the value is zero it is sending the email to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a few issues with your code. First off, if you want the output of a command to be stored in a string, you can encase the command with the `$()` syntax like so:

```
RESULT=$(find /proc -maxdepth 1 -user gen17 -type d -mmin +120 | wc -l)
```

Next, tt looks like you made a mistake on your `if` statement. You have the whole thing in quotes, which makes it treat it as a string (which in this case would always be treated as a true statement). I would imagine the following would work:

```
if [ $RESULT -ge 1 ]
```

or perhaps you were trying something like this:

```
if [ "$RESULT" -ge "1" ]
```

Without testing it myself, I imagine both should work in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your construct is the single string containing the value of `$RESULT` and the literal text `-ge 1`; this is then implicitly checked against zero length. Because the string is never going to be zero length the test returns 1.

> ```
> [ "$RESULT -ge 1" ]
> ```

I think what you need is this

```
[ "$RESULT" -gt 1 ]
```

Comment: Jason, thank you. I got the result..

Comment: can someone help the same on Solaris.. I'm not able to grep the process running more than 2 hours.